# What is an appropriate response to answers that correctly identified a question author's XY problem when my problem really is X?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, specific-answer, xy-problem

The other day I found [How do you write the end of a file opened with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147996/150605), which is a question I had, too.  (Mine was slightly different in that I am not using `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`, but the crux of the matter remains the same: performing the last write operation on a file opened with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`.)  To summarize:

1. The author asks "Is `foo` really the only way to do `X`?"
2. Of the four answers posted...

   - One asks "Are you sure you need to do `X`?"
   - One is the author saying "It turns out I didn't need to do `X`!"
   - One muses about the merits of doing `X` without addressing the question of *how*.
   - One devotes a sentence to using `foo` to do `X`...but then concurs with the answer questioning the need to do `X` at all.
3. **11 years later** I come along, knowing that "No, really, I need to do `X`."
4. 3 out of 4 answers don't attempt to answer the original question of "How do you do `X`?  With `foo`?", so I downvote them because they're not helpful to me.
5. Revisiting the question days later, I wonder if that was the right move and am curious enough to post this very question.

For the two answers that identified the author's question as an `XY` problem, which are the focus of this Meta question, I see the following justifications for downvoting...

- They don't answer the question *as asked*.
- They aren't at all helpful to me, a reader in the future.
- They fail to recognize that `X` is a valid approach in some circumstances.  If it weren't, `X` likely wouldn't exist at all and `Y` would be the only option.
- Maybe things were different back in *(checks notes)* Stack Overflow's first two weeks open to the public, but *today* at least the non-author answer seems like it should be a comment instead of an answer (arguably in this case of the `XY` problem where `Y` is simply the absence of `X`), yet flagging as such would be too strong an action.

...but I can also see the following justifications for upvoting...

- They addressed the author's problem, specifically by identifying an `XY` problem.  That is, they *don't* blindly answer the question *as asked*.
- They would be useful to any other reader with the same `XY` problem.
- Since they were posted the same day/week/month as the question, the Q&A had not yet undergone that implicit transition from "Let's address this problem for this specific user" to "Let's address this problem generally for anyone who might ever have it."  With the focus of the question being solely on solving the author's particular need, they were, at the time they were posted, helpful answers.

...and justifications for doing nothing at all...

- It's not fair to punish an answer because neither it *nor any other posted before or after* are very helpful to me.  It's not the responsibility of each answer to address a question from every possible angle.  They chose to answer from one angle (`Y`) while having no way one of knowing if someone else would later come along and cover the parts they missed/ignored (`X`).  No one ever did, but I can't punish that answer for that.
- It's not fair to punish an answer because the *question* was on the wrong track.
- I only care because I had the same question and 3.5/4 answers weren't helpful to me.  If it were instead 3.5/**5** answers that were unhelpful I'd just ignore those answers and focus on the helpful one.  Therefore, whether it's 3.5/4 or 3.5/5+ my individual responses to the 3.5 answers should be the same.

**TL;DR** Ultimately, for some reason I find myself torn between "I should downvote this answer because it wasn't helpful to me, a person with the same problem" and "I should upvote/ignore this answer because it was helpful to one person, with the potential for more."  Perhaps this is just the first time I'm evaluating an `XY` question that A) I have a vested interest in knowing the answer to `X` but B) all of the answers (largely) focus on `Y`/anything but how to do `X`.  What should one do in that situation?

**Note:**  I realize that, as mentioned above, there is exactly one sentence in the answers that does address how to do `X`, which is certainly a lot different than *zero* sentences.  However, that sentence doesn't instill a lot of confidence in someone searching for the answer, and would be very different if it were more like "Yes, you need to use `foo` to do `X`.  <INSERT SUPPORTING DETAILS HERE>.", which is why I lump it in with the entirely `Y` answers.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to ask about this specific post? Or did you want to do something else?

Comment: No, they should not be comments. They do answer the question. They may not do so in a way you find useful, so it's your prerogative to vote on that, but they make an honest attempt at addressing the issue at hand nonetheless. Putting "answers" in comments just bypasses our quality control, it should not be done.

Comment: I have had a few occasions where I've found somebody asked an XY question with *my problem* as X and people answered with Y. It's really infuriating, since I might then find other questions closed as a dupe to that one. It's even worse if the X refers to some bad practice while Y is doing it "the proper way", yet Y is not an option for my circumstances. Personally, if I find an XY question I try not to answer for Y unless OP rephrases the question, at least.

Comment: @StoryTeller Taking another look at that answer I realize that the middle paragraphs do make the case that the author's approach could be actively harmful to their stated goal, so I see your point.  I think I was focusing on the fact that answer answers a question with a question, which is why I was of the opinion that (by today's standards) an answer premised on feedback from the author they had not yet received is not really a concrete answer, and comments, not answers, should be used to seek such clarification.

Comment: Your question title makes it sound like you want a general approach, but you did tag it with [specific-answer]. Could you clarify what you are willing as an answer please? Because for the title, simply post a new question which explains how it is not the same XY problem. That this question got a response to the Y of the XY problem is simply ok. People may very well also face the same XY problem and they'll find what they need there. Similar but different questions are not an issue. Just be sure to correctly explain how your case is different.

Answer (score 5):

The question you link is old and mostly a relic from a time when SO was more lax overall. It's not representative for the current standards of the site, so it's not really worth dwelling on.

The various answers aren't great, you can ignore them or down-vote them. Or where appropriate flag as "not an answer" for deletion review (which was now done for a bad "thank you" answer).

If you think the specific question is a lost cause and you remain keen on improving the quality, then the best thing you can do is to find a better question about the same issue. Or if you can't find one, ask a better question yourself (it's fine to even answer it yourself). Hopefully, you'll end up with something with better answers. We can then close the old question down as a duplicate to the better one.

In the end, technical quality and correctness is the most important.

Comment: An alternative would be to answer the old question with the correct answer.

Comment: @JL2210 Not a good idea if the question was indeed an "XY problem".

Comment: "Would your response to the answers be different if they were, say, 1 year old instead of 11?" and "Would I have a case that asking the same thing in a new question would not be a duplicate?" were going to be my "bonus questions" at the end, but I figured I'd stick to the one-question-per-question norm.  I am surprised to see the author's own answer get deleted because it was the only one that could definitely say "This is the solution", plus it included some performance numbers as well, but I guess the feeling is it didn't add any more information than simply accepting the other answer would?